# Draw a line between two excel cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to draw a line between the centers of two ( non-adjacent ) cells in an Excel work sheet using openpyxl.

Using openpyxl I have created a fairly large lookup table. Many of the points in the lookup table are interpolated from a hand full of known points.

I would like to draw lines between the cells that were created using the known points. These lines would sort of circle the areas that are interpolated.

Expected Result:
(This is the actual Excel generated spread sheet, The lines were added by hand in Excel. I want to automate the line drawing. )

[image]

In this case the white cells are known data points. Green(ish) cells are inside of the bounding trianges. Redish-Blueish are outside.
All of data on this sheet was populated via a new sheet using openpyxl.

The openpyxl documention hints that this is possible but I do not understand how.

Something along the lines of:

```
ws.Line['A1':'P17].style['heavy','black']
```

I think is what I am looking for.

[A bit more data ]

Using Excel and win32com I can automate drawing these lines.

```
line = ws.Shapes.Addline(3,4,70,80).Line
```

However do to other limitations in Excel I have to create this offline using openpyxl.  [Other_Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639467/setting-the-color-of-a-large-number-of-excel-cells-quickly)
So to re-phrase my question:
**Can openpyxl even draw lines?**

I am beginning to think that I will have to create the spreadsheet with openpyxl then open the newly created workbook with Excel and draw the lines with Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my original Question was if this can be done with **Openpyxl**.
That question still stands.

However here is my solution to draw lines with win32com / Python in Excel directly.
This is not ideal for my situation but it works.

```
def Drawline(Sheet,Start,End):
    StartCell = Sheet.Cells(Start[0],Start[1])
    StartAdjacent = Sheet.Cells(Start[0]+1,Start[1]+1)
    EndCell = Sheet.Cells(End[0],End[1])
    EndAdjacent = Sheet.Cells(End[0]+1,End[1]+1)
    Y1 = ( StartCell.Top + StartAdjacent.Top ) / 2
    X1 = ( StartCell.Left + StartAdjacent.Left ) / 2
    Y2 = ( EndCell.Top + EndAdjacent.Top ) / 2
    X2 = ( EndCell.Left + EndAdjacent.Left ) / 2
    Sheet.Shapes.AddLine(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)
```

This will draw a line from the center of Start to the center of End on Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think Excel is suitable for this. The drawing subsystem uses a completely different coordinate system to the worksheet itself. Thus, although it is possible to "anchor" a drawing between two cells, the proportions will be extremely hard to calculate.

I'm sure matplotlib, seaborn or other graphics libraries have tools more suitable for this job.

Comment: Excel is not the ideal tool. I agree. However it is what I am stuck with. The results of this spreadsheet are used in other spreadsheets. Both the results and coloring are used in the other sheets. The Lines are just to help visualize where some of the data came from in the mapping.